# How to efficiently use logging in Google App Engine python application?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

How can I print log messages for debugging purposes in a [Google Cloud Endpoints Frameworks](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/about-cloud-endpoints-frameworks) application implemented in python?

Since [Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/about-cloud-endpoints-frameworks) apps are deployed on [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/), I followed the App Engine's docs on [Reading and Writing Application logs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/logs/), and I tried to find my log messages on the GAE [console logs](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs).

That did not help much though even with using all the available filters, since most log entries have hundreds of lines of nested JSON objects, and my log message will be buried in then among metadata and unrelated info in one log entry.

Is there a way to print and view log messages like I do with a simple python application running on my local machine?

Answer (score 0):

You can add any filter you want in the [Logs Viewer](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/quickstart-sdk#explore). Once in there, in the dialog box that says "Filter by label or text search" you can add your filter. i.e:

```
resource.type="api"
resource.labels.service="[YOUR-PROJECT-ID].appspot.com"
resource.labels.method="v1.[YOUR-PROJECT-ID].EchoApi_echo"
severity="DEBUG"
```

These filters may vary a bit, as you may have different versions, methods etc. To familiarize yourself with these filters, if you follow this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/get-started-frameworks-python) once you have finished deploying your API:

1. in the section [Tracking API activity](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/get-started-frameworks-python#track_api) click on "View Endpoints Request Logs".
2. There you will see that it automatically filtered the results by
   "Produced API" -> "Service you created" -> "Method created".
3. If you click in any of the Logs entries, you can click in any of its fields, for example click on "severity". It will say: "Show matching entries"
4. It will automatically create an advanced filter similar to the one I wrote before.

Also [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-filters) you have more detailed info about using advanced filters in log viewer. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#logseverity) about the different severity for the events (In your case looks like you are looking for severity ="DEBUG" )